# Batch File: Ping Domain & get IP and show result with text

Tags: batch-file

## Situation

I have 2 Email Hosting with a lot of domain.

Ej:
https://domain1.com is hosted in the server1 that ip is 1.1.1.1
https://domain2.com is hosted in the server2 that ip is 2.2.2.2
https://domain3.com is hosted in the server2 that ip is 2.2.2.2
https://domain4.com is hosted in the server1 that ip is 1.1.1.1

## Script Function:

> -The user input the domain.
>   -The script yould be ping to domain, if the domain ip is 1.1.1.1 the script should by show (This domain is hosted in "Server1"). But if the domain is 2.2.2.2 the system show by inform (This domain is hosted in "Server2").

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p Domain=Ingrese DomainName: 
set server1=1.1.1.1
set server2=2.2.2.2

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a IN ('ping -n 1 !Domain!') DO (
 if "%%b" NEQ "" set ip=%%b
)
echo IP.....%ip%


IF %ip% == !server1! echo server1

IF %ip% == !server2! echo server2

pause
```

## PROBLEM:

I don't know who to do this:

> -If the IP Domain doesn't mach with Server1 or Server2, said Domain Not Mach. 
>   -Also if the IP Domain is not resolved because not responce or doesn't exist, said Domain Doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there really a space in `domain`? That would be two parameters to `ping`. Try `ping -n 1 "!Domain!"` (btw: you don't need delayed expansion in your code (unless the shown code is embedded in another `for` or `if` block))

Comment: IF i delete the delayed expansion, this part didn't work "ping -n 1 !Domain!" i need change to "ping -n 1 %Domain%". I need if the user ingress a Domain and this Domain is not equal to Server 1 or Server 2 IP, the script should be show didn't mach or If the Domain not response because the TTL is 0 o null show the domain Not Response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a predefined variable:

```
echo IP.....%ip%
set "srv=Domain Doesn't exist."
IF %ip% == %server1% set "srv=Server1"
IF %ip% == %server2% set "srv=Server2"
echo %srv%
pause
```